# Architecture of a CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system

I am building a custom Content Management System for my client, using C#2008, ASP.Net technology. I am looking for advice regarding the architecture (application layout, database layout etc) of such a system.

Anyone here have any experience design / developing such a system? Any websites that I can get more information from?

Any open source CMS out there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what kind of content? CM and ECM have multiple meanings, depending on what kinds of documents, structured, unstructured or semistructured information is being handled, and for what purposes and user base.

Comment: It is going to be something similar to MyYahoo (customizable, corporate intranet). Big project, so I am looking for ideas / best practices etc.

Comment: Content is going to be corporate news, department news, external news (like a feed from CNN or CNNSI or webservice from Weather.com etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any open source CMS out there?

Check out Umbraco, its very good, not suitable for everything (depends on your sites content really) but you get so much for free that it would be silly to not give it a look over, its not a small bedroom hack up job.

Regarding creating your own CMS, I'd probably try to steer you away from it, its not for the faint of heart unless your content demands are very niche. Even then its better to build on top of something else if at all possible.

ASP.net MVC would be worth a look too if you are going down that code your own route, would save you some headaches.

Comment: This does look like what I am looking for. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have had first hand experience with Umbraco v3. It does a job, but I probably wouldn't use it again. Found it to be quite buggy esp the WYSIWIG editor.

Comment: V4 has a completely new front end and I've had no problems with it myself. V5 is due out soon I hear which will have even more goodies and code fixes in it.

Answer (score 1):

[DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) is a good open source CMS is specifically for ASP.NET development. Definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a blog post about content modeling and data stores for content management systems. I think it could be useful: [Blog post: Get more out of your content: content modeling and data stores](http://www.webnodes.com/get-more-out-of-your-content-content-modeling-and-data-stores)